# draw border around ui textlabel

Tags: matlab, user-interface

The ui element for text in matlab does not have a border property.

If I could however loop over all text ui elements get and their pixel position I could possibily draw a simple rectangle around them.

However I do not know how to loop over all ui text elements.

Comment: How about using a non-clickable button instead of static text? Or a `uitable` with no column/row headers and a single cell?

Comment: I could as well use an edit control and make it inactive. I would nevertheless be interested in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is to find all textboxes: have you seen "[findall](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/findall.html)" function?

```
 hA = findall(gcf,'Style','text')
```

Once you've got an array of textbox handles, for an each individual handle, you may, for example, create an underlying textbox with different "background color" property.

To test this, I did the flowing:

1. launch guide
2. create a textbox1
3. set textbox1.units to pixels
4. create textbox2
5. set textbox2.BackgroundColor to red
6. set

   ```
   texttox2.position.x = texttox1.position.x-1
   texttox2.position.y = texttox1.position.y-1
   texttox2.position.w = texttox1.position.w+2
   texttox2.position.h = texttox1.position.h+2
   ```

Here's my result:
[image: my result]